# Excel Macro needed which can check the downloads folder and delete all the files except the latest downloaded file

Tags: vba, excel

I want to make an excel file which would do the following steps:

1. Delete all the excel files from the downloads folder except for the one latest downloaded file.
2. Make a copy of that excel file names as "Data.xls" and system makes a "Beep" sound
3. Repeat the above mentioned two steps every 15 minutes

I can do this in Visual Basic but unable to implement that in Excel Macro...

Please help.. My promotion depends on that  :-)

Comment: Please post your code that does it in VB

Comment: Copy your VB module into Excel. Make the main sub public. Add a macro. Tell the macro to run your sub. If you can't do that, there is the sliiiiiight possibility that you did not write your VB code.

Comment: OKay. U'll try that and let you know. Does it mean that my timer event from the VB will also work in the Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Set a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime.  The images below shows the classes available in the Object Browser.  I usually use this for file-related tasks in VBA.  I did some research & the Microsoft Scripting Runtime is standard on Windows so everyone should have it

[image]